# Calling JavaScript from inside HTML?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

New to JavaScript, and what I'm doing below seems right from all the Google RTFM'ing I've been doing, but it isn't working. So I decided to reach out for help since I'm stuck.

I have a JavaScript that lives in my HTML's < head> document...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

The contents are the Google Maps API. Previously I've had the JavaScript run from a DIV onMouseOver. This way I could run the script multiple times - because I need multiple different maps per page (it's a photoblog). I know the script works, because it's working today.

```
<div class="location" onmouseover="initalizeMap('gmaps1832588575', '42.102500,-72.587333')"></div>
```

I am trying to figure out how to have this script called from outside of a div. For example, a static div that always displays the map. So, I was under the impression I can move the initializeMap function out of the onmouseover, and into it's own < script> section. However, it's not working. Here's what I have:

```
    <div class="location">
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.756167+-73.978833&z=14" target="_blank">New York, NY, US</a>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">initalizeMap('gmaps2021396674', '40.756167,-73.978833');</script>

    <div class="map_holder">
    <div class="map" id="gmaps2021396674">
    </div></div></div>
```

Like I said, I need this to run multiple times, and this code works when I call on it from a div onMouseOver.

Comment: You might want to look into how javascript functions work. Here is how javascript functions are used and defined, by w3 - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've done the Hello World function, and like I said, the function I have now works when called from an onmouseover. Trying to get it to work outside of the div, but still using the random ID to call back to that div at a later process.

Comment: Can you be more precise please, what do you picture when you say "outside the div"?

Comment: My original post has a lot of info in it already. I'm trying to load a unique div, which will show a unique google map, up to 5 times a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put code inside a script tag within the page, it runs as soon as that script tag is loaded.  This may be before the div it is referring to has been loaded, so it doesn't work because it's running too early (the mouseover approach worked because you can't do your mouseover until the qhole page loads).

You can try moving your script tag to the end of the page, or you can trigger it from the HTML body tag's onload event, or you can look at jQuery and use $(document).ready().

Comment: The way I have it now, is the < script> is loading before the div loads in the HTML, however it may be too fast for it to grab the Google API. 

If I do onload, or if I load it at the end of the page, then I can only load the script once, right? Since this is for a photo blog that will display up to 5 unique maps per page, how can I best do this?

Comment: Can't you put it in onload and do all 5 from there?

Comment: Perhaps I could, but in order for the map to load 5 unique places, for 5 unique photos (in 5 unique divs), I use a random number generator so that the script knows which div to load which map. Not sure how I can do that with an onload. That's the newbie in me shining through

Comment: It sounds like you're doing stuff you haven't showed us the code for.  Where do the random numbers get applied?  In the example you give, how  do you figure out what div to target if the name contains a random number?

Comment: Here's my complete function. It's for Wordpress and it utilizes a plugin which stores latitude and longitude in a meta field in mysql. It's a rather long plugin, with many different things going on. I'm only showing the part in the plugin that finds if the photo has meta data, and to extract that info and create the div, with the random unique identifier. here: http://pastebin.com/yk3Uqfst. Line 23 is where the random ID is created which Google Maps API uses to know which map coordinates to load into which div.

Comment: This works great with the onmouseover because the plugin only gets called whenever you hover over the div that displays the map information. But I'd like to be able to display the unique maps up front without having to hover over the magic div -- if its possible

Comment: OK, so it looks like your doing all the random number stuff in PHP, so that by the time you're generating javascript, you know all of the ids.  So why not just do (in onLoad) `initializeMap("12345");initializeMap("45635234");initializeMap("24534634");` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

What condition triggers a call to initializeMap? Previously, you had it called when a mouseOver occurred. If you move it out of the event handler, it'll only get called once.

Something has to trigger its invocation. I'd figure out what you want to cause it to be called. Do you, perhaps, need a timer?

Comment: Good question, a timer may be suitable, however since i need the script to be called 5 times, using a random ID generated for each div, it presents a challenge for me to be able to run the script 5 times, using the same random number for the div ID.